# Android 6 получить mac WiFi

Tags: android, wifi, permissions

Добрый день. Я хочу получить MAC адрес wifi.

В Manifest прописал :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Вызываю `requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE},1);`

И тут ловлю

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (grantResults.length >  && grantResults[0] PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                final WifiInfo info = manager.getConnectionInfo();
                String address = info.getMacAddress();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ПРАВА ПОЛУЧЕНЫ mac: " + address,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ПРАВА НЕ ПОЛУЧЕНЫ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Сообщение выводится что права получены, но MAC = "02:00:00:00:00:00"

Как получить MAC на Android 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не получится его получить на андроид 6
https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id они отключили такую возможность((
и возвращают дефолтное значение "02:00:00:00:00:00"

Comment: Мне нужен мой mac адрес, mac адаптера, который стоит в устройстве (телефоне) и он как правило без рута не меняем. Mac нужен для регистрации приложения.

Comment: @ScreamNight, в Android 6 запретили получать MAC адресс для WIFI и Bluetooth. Вы не сможете его получить без Root (для Bluetooth пока есть способ обойти это ограничение)

Answer (score 0):

В андроид 6 можно получить мак без рута.

```
 List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface nif : all) {
            if (!nif.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) continue;

            byte[] macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
            if (macBytes == null) {
                return "";
            }

            StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b : macBytes) {
                res1.append(String.format("%02X:",b));
            }

            if (res1.length() > 0) {
                res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
            }
            return res1.toString();
        }
```